# Click to reveal and hide menu

Tags: javascript, jquery

Why can I click "project info" in this code to reveal the text but cant click it again to get hide the text. I am in experienced with javascript and have made a mess of the code...any help would be appreciated greatly. Here is the html code:

```
<div  class:"descinner;" style="position:fixed; left:260px; top:595px;">
  <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="showDesc" style="display: inline; ">Project info</a>
  <div style="width: 500px; background-image: initial; background-attachment: initial; background-origin: initial; background-clip: initial; background-color:#fff; opacity: 0.9; position: fixed; margin-top: 10px; margin-left: 100px;  font-size: 14px; font-weight:bold; line-height: 125%; display: none; background-position: fixed; ">
    Exces eturio. Ipis eos autatus ad quia cum santo doluptio que dignatenis dipsam non cuptam, tectaer iosaperiam repudi imo quaerum resciet acercianis apedipsam dellendae nobis am raectotatur, cum expla enit placcup tasitium quias qui quia illaceribus quiates dolecte occusandit anduntibus doluptat.               
  </div>
</div>
```

and here is the script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var descShow = false;
  $('.showDesc').click(function(){
    $(this).hide();
    $(this).next().show();
    $('.descInner').css();                      
    descShow = true;
  });

  var ee;
  $('body').click(function(e){
    e = window.event || e; 
    ee = e;

    var node = e.srcElement || e.target;
    var $node = $(node);

    if(node=='javascript:void(0);'){
      return;
    }

    while ($node.html()!=null){
      if($node.hasClass('descInner')){
        $('.showDesc').next().hide();
        $('.showDesc').show();
        $('.descInner').css();
        descShow = false;
        return;
      }
      $node = $node.parent();
    };
});
</script>
```

Comment: `<div  class:"descinner;"` ? class="descinner"? typo in the post or in your code? Still reading through...

Comment: Still not sure of the problem. Really new to javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all you want to do is show the text when you click the link, then hide it on a body click, use something like this. Working example can be found here: http://jsfiddle.net/vb9NU/

```
$('.showDesc').click(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation(); 
    $(this).hide().next().show(); // hides the link, shows the next div
    // $('.cssclass').show(); // if you want to make the div a css class, bit easier incase you change your markup (INSTEAD of .next().show() above)
});

$('body').click(function() { 
    $('.showDesc').show().next().hide(); // (if you make the div to show/hide based on a selector instead of next(), do a similar sort of thing as above
});
```

e.stopPropagation() stops the click of the link 'bubbling up'  to the browser thinking its ALSO a body click (which would result in it immediately showing then hiding it).

I apologise if I didn't understand what you were after. Just FYI, `$node` is a div element, not a string as well.

Try using `console.log(whateveryouwanttolog)` e.g. `console.log($node)` to see the value of a variable in the console (in firebug or in chrome/safari developer tools). It makes things a lot easier :)

Comment: Thanks, it worked. But, how can I make it so that the text button that is originally clicked to reveal stays in the same place after being clicked (rather than disappearing) and can be clicked to hide the body text?

Comment: Like this you mean? http://jsfiddle.net/vb9NU/1/ If you don't need the text to disappear on body click, but only want it on the click of the link, then we just use toggle :) (like this: http://jsfiddle.net/vb9NU/2/)

Comment: No problem! :) This might help you in future (its quite old and excludes a number of newer functions, but its quite a good reference, its a jquery cheat sheet: http://colorcharge.com/jquery/. Just one note, you don't need the `@` in the `@attr` on there. jQuery is really quite logical when you know some of the main traversing/getting/setting functions :)